# Can't install testrpc [npm error]

Tags: testrpc, nodejs

getting the following error.

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-87-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/n/versions/node/8.2.1/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ethereumjs-testrpc"
npm ERR! node v8.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND

npm ERR! Cannot find module 'ansi'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

Can someone help?

Comment: try npm install and then your command

Comment: Have you installed testrpc as specified [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions). When posting questions, please provide how you got the error,i.e., what all steps/commands you executed which ran into errors.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. First I removed nodejs using sudo apt-get remove nodejs
Then installed it again and then I installed testrpc and truffle

Answer (score 0):

I think one should use Docker container like alpine to play with frameworks like truffle. That will definitely reduce the headache of installing and setting up the environment. Alougth in case of nodejs installation error it's already preferable to reinstall it.